# Submit span content to a database

Tags: javascript, php, html

Just for fun, I'm trying to build a simple time tracker; the page grabs a stored duration from a database, and you can then add more time to that value, and then store it back to the database.

The value is displayed in h:i:s format, but there's also a hidden span with the same time but just in seconds.

My problem:

I cannot figure out how to submit the contents of the span to the database.
If I instead put the hidden span contents inside a form input, then the content doesn't change; it just submits the original value back to the database.

I really feel like I'm making a bit of a meal out of this.

Here's the current code...

```
<?php

/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
CREATE TABLE my_table (t TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('00:01:50');
*/

require('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');


//wip - for later - and remember to remove the injection!!!
if(sizeof($_POST) != 0){
$query = "UPDATE my_table SET t=SEC_TO_TIME({$_GET['tts']}) LIMIT 1";
$pdo->query($query);
}

//Grab the stored value from the database
$query = "
select t
     , time_to_sec(t) tts
     , LPAD(HOUR(t),2,0) h
     , LPAD(MINUTE(t),2,0) i
     , LPAD(SECOND(t),2,0) s
  from my_table
 limit 1
   ";

if ($data = $pdo->query($query)->fetch()) {
$t = $data['t'];
$tts = $data['tts'];
$h = $data['h'];
$i = $data['i'];
$s = $data['s'];

} else {
$t = 0;
$tts = 0;
$h = '00';
$i = '00';
$s = '00';
}

?>

#relevant code starts  here, I guess

<div>
<div>
<span hidden id="tts"><?php echo $tts; ?></span>
<span id="hour"><?php echo $h; ?></span>:
<span id="min"><?php echo $i; ?></span>:
<span id="sec"><?php echo $s; ?></span>

<input id="startButton" type="button" value="Start/Resume">
<input id="pauseButton" type="button" value="Pause">

<button id="submit" onclick="myFunction()" >Save</button>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var Clock = {
  totalSeconds: <?php echo $tts ?>,
  start: function () {
    if (!this.interval) {
        var self = this;
        function pad(val) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
          self.totalSeconds += 1;

          $("#hour").text(pad(Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 3600 % 60)));
          $("#min").text(pad(Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 60 % 60)));
          $("#sec").text(pad(parseInt(self.totalSeconds % 60)));
          $("#tts").text(pad(parseInt(self.totalSeconds)));

        }, 1000);
    }
  },

  pause: function () {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    delete this.interval;
  },

  resume: function () {
    this.start();
  }
};


$('#startButton').click(function () { Clock.start(); });
$('#pauseButton').click(function () { Clock.pause(); });
</script>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
  div.querySelectorAll('span')
    .forEach(span => console.log(span.textContent));
});
}


</script>
```

Comment: Either AJAX the textContent OR copy the span content to hidden input fields. You can also style input fields as text and they will also be submitted if they have a name and a value

Comment: _“f I instead put the hidden span contents inside a form input, then the content doesn't change”_ - likely due to the fact that the content gets set using `.text()`, whereas for input fields you’d have to use `.val()`

Comment: @CBroe Thanks - I think that might be just the nudge I needed!...

Answer (score 1):

With CBroe's useful hint, the following works... although my attempts at preparing and binding $_GET are failing at the moment, so the query itself remains insecure...

```
<?php

/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
CREATE TABLE my_table (t TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('00:01:50');
*/

require('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');


if(sizeof($_GET) != 0){
$query = "UPDATE my_table SET t = SEC_TO_TIME({$_GET['tts']}) LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
}

//Grab the stored value from the database
$query = "
select t
     , time_to_sec(t) tts
     , LPAD(HOUR(t),2,0) h
     , LPAD(MINUTE(t),2,0) i
     , LPAD(SECOND(t),2,0) s
  from my_table
 limit 1
   ";

if ($data = $pdo->query($query)->fetch()) {
$t = $data['t'];
$tts = $data['tts'];
$h = $data['h'];
$i = $data['i'];
$s = $data['s'];

} else {
$t = 0;
$tts = 0;
$h = '00';
$i = '00';
$s = '00';
}

?>

#relevant code starts  here, I guess

<form id="myForm">
<input name="tts" type= "hidden" id="tts" value="tts">
<span id="hour"><?php echo $h; ?></span>:
<span id="min"><?php echo $i; ?></span>:
<span id="sec"><?php echo $s; ?></span>

<input id="startButton" type="button" value="Start/Resume">
<input id="pauseButton" type="button" value="Pause">

<button id="submit" onclick="myFunction()" >Save</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var Clock = {
  totalSeconds: <?php echo $tts ?>,
  start: function () {
    if (!this.interval) {
        var self = this;
        function pad(val) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
          self.totalSeconds += 1;

          $("#hour").text(pad(Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 3600 % 60)));
          $("#min").text(pad(Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 60 % 60)));
          $("#sec").text(pad(parseInt(self.totalSeconds % 60)));
          $("#tts").val(pad(parseInt(self.totalSeconds)));

        }, 1000);
    }
  },

  pause: function () {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    delete this.interval;
  },

  resume: function () {
    this.start();
  }
};


$('#startButton').click(function () { Clock.start(); });
$('#pauseButton').click(function () { Clock.pause(); });
</script>

<script>

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
}


</script>
```